# Div updated with AJAX result loses update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've set up a simple page that is supposed to update a div with the result of an AJAX call. It sort-of works: the service is called, the correct result is returned, the result text will appear in the div, but as soon as I dismiss the message box, the div reverts.

The Javascript I'm using looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        function callTestService()
        {
            $.ajax
            ({ 
                url: '/testService/'+document.getElementById('textInput1').value,
                type: 'get',
                error: function ()
                {
                    alert("Error!");
                }
            }).done(function (data)
                    {
                        //$('#resultsDiv').html(data);
                        document.getElementById("resultsDiv").innerHTML = data;
                        alert("Done!");
                    }) ;
        }
    </script>
    <div id="resultsDiv" style="min-height: 50px; min-width: 50px; " />
    <form onsubmit="callTestService()">
        <input id="textInput" />
        <button>Done!</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Where do you call your function ? You must have another function/script modifying the div, or maybe calling twice this function, the second time giving an empty result

Comment: you're right... updating code sample...

Comment: Just for grins, change two divs with the result, and see if both of them are reverted. I think your code is solid, and some other part of your program may be reverting the div in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Igor's answer is most likely correct (hard to tell since we don't have the rest of your program). You should also be able to return false from your form handler, so that the browser will not actually submit the form and refresh the page.

Or

```
<form onsubmit="callTestService(); return false">
```

Answer (score 2):

The default type of `button` html element is `submit`. After your `ajax` call, the form is submitted and therefore the page is reloaded with its original html that comes from server. Change:

```
<form>
  <input id="textInput" />
  <button type="button" onclick="callTestService()">Done!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Good catch. That sounds like the problem. You should also be able to return false from the form submit handler, which will not refresh the page

Comment: Hmm nope, that's not working for me. The div still reverts after I dismiss the dialogue. If you want this to work, you have to add `return false` after the reference to the onClick function, as in Keith's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can cause the problem, but your markup is invalid:

```
<div id="resultsDiv" style="min-height: 50px; min-width: 50px; " />
```

Should be:

```
<div id="resultsDiv" style="min-height: 50px; min-width: 50px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this using ajax success method and without form submit i.e:

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    $("#myBtn").click(function()
    {
        $.ajax
        ({ 
            url: '/testService/'+document.getElementById('textInput1').value,
            type: 'get',
            error: function ()
            {
                alert("Error!");
            };
            success: function (data)
            {
                    alert("Done!");
                    $('#resultsDiv').html(data);
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="resultsDiv" style="min-height: 50px; min-width: 50px;"></div>
<form>
    <input id="textInput" />
    <input type="button" id="myBtn">Done!</button>
</form>
```

Furthermore div tag is a container tag hence it needs to be close i.e `<div></div>`

Comment: Just as a note, jQuery has deprecated success(), and you should be moving to its equivalent done() as indicated in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function callTestService() {
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: '/testService/' + document.getElementById('textInput1').value,
            type: 'get',
            error: function () {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
            //$('#resultsDiv').html(data);
            document.getElementById("resultsDiv").innerHTML = data;
            alert("Done!");
        });

        return false;
    }

</script>
<div id="resultsDiv" style="min-height: 50px; min-width: 50px; "> </div>
<form onsubmit="return callTestService(); ">
    <input id="textInput" />
    <button>Done!</button>
</form>
```